# Java Queue, entire Queue is replaced by new added element

Tags: java, queue

I am working on a project for school that have jobs(an int array), i am new to Java and have encountered a strange error while trying to put these jobs in a Queue.
 My problem is that once i already have one element in the Queue, the next element replaces the previous element in the queue,
i.e if `Queue[0]` holds arr1, and i add the next element `( Queue.add(arr2))`, arr 2 gets added to `Queue[1]` but Queue also replaces `Queue[0]` with arr2. 
There is a lot of code so i have only posted i am using and where the function where it is called, the element change happens as soon as .add is executed.

```
public class drumQueue {

    private Queue<int[]> myQueue = new LinkedList<int[]>();
    private static boolean drumIsBusy = false;
    int index=0;

    public void add(int[] p){
        myQueue.add(p); 
    }

    public void remove(){
        myQueue.remove();
    }

    public int[] getP(){
        System.out.println("POPED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        return myQueue.poll();
    }

    public boolean isDrumIsBusy() {
        return drumIsBusy;
    }

    public void setDrumIsBusy(boolean drumIsBusy) {
        drumQueue.drumIsBusy = drumIsBusy;
    }
    public void print(){
        for( int i =0 ;i < myQueue.size(); i++ ){
            System.out.println(myQueue.peek()[1]+ "ELEMENT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        }
    }
    public int size(){
        return myQueue.size();
    }
}
```

Method that uses above class in a different class.

```
private static void MemeoryManager(int[] a, int[] p) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    memoryLink.freeSpaceTableBuilder();
    memoryLink.freeSpaceTableBuilder();
    p[2] = memoryLink.addressFinder(p[3]);
    memoryLink.addTooMemory(p[2],p[3],p[1]);
    memoryLink.merge();

    drumQueue.add(p);

    Swap(a,0);
}
```

Comment: You will want to create and post a valid [mcve] (please read the link before replying).

Comment: Why is `boolean drumIsBusy` static?

Comment: And why are you seemingly calling the add method on the `drumQueue` class, not an instance? Note that as an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

Comment: What was the purpose of showing all the code with `memoryLink`? How is it relevant to your question?

Answer (score 1):

I think you class store data in proper way, but it have a problem in `print()` method. `peek()` **always** return head of the queue, so you just print first element `size()` times. Try to use `queue.toArray()` for printing purposes